# how to relate a category with subcategory and display in gridview using databind in asp.net using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

how to relate category with subcategory and display the data in grid view with databound from database in asp.net?

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
                bind();
        }
    }

private void bind()
{
    string subcat1 = "" + Session["subcat"];
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from catsubcat where subcategory='" + subcat1 + "' and category='electronics'", Class1.getconnectionstring());
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adp.Fill(ds);
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();

}
```

Comment: What exactly do you need ? What is the problem you are having ? Do you want to show categories along with their sub categories in a gridview ? Also its better if you use parameterized queries.

Comment: ohh Long time I hadn't seen the `DataSet` so cute... brings me memories back

Comment: check this link: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rohatash/showing-category-and-subcategory-using-nested-gridview-in-as/

Comment: Is it master child grid that you are looking for ?

Comment: Nice example http://www.progtalk.com/viewarticle.aspx?articleid=54
You could tweek it to suit your purpose

Comment: i have two coloumns in databse category and subcategory.i added a dropdown list to category and subcategory.when i should select the category the related subcategory must get selected.and related information  from database be retrieved and must be displayed in grid view on clicking a button?how this is to be done in asp.net using c#?